# How can I remotely check if two SQL data rows are identical, without sending all data between the servers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, synchronization

I'm building an API to allow remote systems to synchronise millions of rows with my source table (one-way).

How can I remotely check if two SQL data rows are identical, without sending all data between the servers?  I have considered using a LastUpdated column but worried that one day, someone might manually edit a record to fix a problem and the systems will then forever be out of sync.

I'm aware of the `checksum(*)` option, but this seems like there could be (largely theoretical) edge cases where the checksum for an updated row might be the same as previously.

The idea is, that my API will provide a list of IDs (primary keys), followed by a "check" value which the remote systems can then use to find out which records they need to add or update. Hopefully this is a sensible approach to keeping the two systems in sync, but I can't find any "best practice" type articles for this.

Comment: Have you looked into replication? It does all this right out of the box.

Comment: You may want to look into replication. Master - slave.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html

Or use something like https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqldbcompare.html

Comment: Sorry but the database systems are different so replication is not an option. Plus there could be multiple different 'subscribers' of different types.

Answer (score -1):

Each table has a rowversionrowversion and rowversionOther

From A synch

```
select b.id 
  from tableA a 
  join tableB b 
    on a.ID = b.ID 
   and b.rowversion != a.rowversionOther
```

After a data synch then needs to update b.rowversionOther = a.rowversion or would get into a vicious cycle.

If a and b update before synch would need to determine the master.

Comment: viscous  = vicious

Comment: I don't actually understand the sentence after the code sample.